# Casting concrete object to 'Object' in C#

Tags: c#, casting

Below code has compile time error

```
ITypeSearch<Object> productSearchCollection = null; // initialising interface object with null
productSearchCollection = SomeMethod.SearchProduct(inputForSearch, facetName, facetValue);
```

> Compile time error : cannot implicitly convert type 'Episerver.Find.ITypeSearch<Searchingindex.common.bibligraphicinformation>' to 'Episerver.Find.ITypeSearch<object>' object . An explicity conversion exists (are you missing cast)

Comment: What is the return type of `SomeMethod.SearchProduct`?

Comment: bibligraphicinformation object

Comment: Why not explicitly cast it? `(object)SomeMethod.SearchProduct(inputForSearch, facetName, facetValue);`

Comment: Do you absolutely have to initialize `productSearchCollection` before the query?

Comment: Share the signature of `SomeMethod.SearchProduct` with us.

Comment: Hi Dortimer , it gives error in explicit cast cannot convert explicit type 'object' to 'IType<Search>' object

Comment: `initialising interface object`? No, that's not an object. It's a *reference* which isn't referring to anything because you initialize it to null. A reference to an object is not an object. Sounds pedantic, but the distinction is very important. Also, "interface object" is a somewhat misleading term as well; there are objects which implement interfaces, however.

Comment: public EPiServer.Find.ITypeSearch<Ipp.SearchIndexing.Common.BibliographicInformation> SomeMethod(SearchInput inputForSearch, string facetName, string facetValue)

Comment: @Dortimer I dont think thats a very good idea.

Comment: Why not explicitly declare `ITypeSearch<Searchingindex.common.bibligraphicinformation> productSearchCollection;`? Or let the compiler figure out the type; don't declare it beforehand, just write `var productSearchCollection = SomeMethod.SearchProduct(inputForSearch, facetName, facetValue);`

Comment: What's the variance set to on `ITypeSearch`'s generic type parameter? I'm guessing it's invariant. If it were Covariant, you would be able to assign a more derived parameter to a more base one.

Comment: @JonathonChase Source [here](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=find/8/5D7F3093)

Comment: The reason i can't declare explicitly is there are different objects assigned on runtime to this ITypeSearch<Object> productSearchCollection = null

Comment: @dinesh "Because I'm trying to do something else equally impossible" won't make it possible to do something impossible. I suggest doing something possible instead. You need to show us a lot more of your code, so we can help you solve that underlying problem that brought you to this dismal pass.

Comment: @dinesh there really isnt a good way to do what you are asking, I _strongly_ suggest refactoring the code.  Its not really plausible to initialize references to generic types when the generic type parameter could be different. Using `object` is a really, really bad way to try and circumvent that

Comment: @maccettura Oh, for sure it's a bad idea, but based on what little information we've been provided, it's hard to suggest any good ideas.

Comment: @Ed , its old code , i thought if any way i can find solution